How to query for duplicate values
I have a table where certain values have relationships with each other (value d is nested under value c, which is nested under group b, in separate tables). Example below:



A
Group B
Value C
Value D




1
10
100
1000


2
11
100
1001


3
12
101
1002


4
13
102
1003


5
14
103
1004


6
14
103
1005


7
14
103
1006


8
15
104
1007


9
16
105
1008


10
16
105
1009



I'm writing a query that wants to pull for situations where for the same value c, value d and group b are different. So for my query, I would want to pull the below from the above table



A
Group B
Value C
Value D




1
10
100
1000


2
11
100
1001



I want to return rows 1 and 2 because group b differs, but value c is the same. I don't want to return rows 3 and 4, because all of group b, value c, and value d have different values. I don't want to return rows 5-7 because group b is the same for each. I don't want to return row 8 because there is no additional row with the same value c, and I don't want to return rows 9 and 10 because, like rows 5-7, group b is the same for each.
The query I have now is
select * 
from table1 
where value c in (select value c 
                  from table 1 
                  group by value c 
                  having count(value c) > 1) 
  and value b in (select value b 
                  from table 1 
                  group by value b 
                  having count(value b) > 1) 
  and value d is not null 
order by 
    value c;

It almost works, but it would return rows 5-7, since even though value b is the same value, it occurs more than once. I'm doing this in SQL Developer with a database to which I have read-only access. Thanks!
Edit: fiddle with table...for some reason the only select statement i've been able to get to work with this is select * from the table? I'm using Oracle 19c on my machine, but 18c in Fiddle.

Please provide your sample data as text rather than as image because people can't copy data from images to try out solutions. Also tag the RDBMS you use.

Make it easy to assist you, create a fiddle (i.e table and data), https://dbfiddle.uk/H1CvCxVu can be used. And put the link to it in your question.

Sorry about that, thanks! I've updated the tables and added a link to fiddle with table and data. I'm using Oracle 19c, but used 18c in fiddle.

Hello you can try this :
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT Value_C
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY Value_C
    HAVING COUNT(Value_C) > 1 AND MAX(Group_B) <> MIN(Group_B)
) dv ON t.Value_C = dv.Value_C
WHERE t.Value_D IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t.Value_C;

Output

you can check this here : https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=6d41ceb3-75e2-4ffa-9df6-a7c83a3b73c1

Oracle is not good in subqueries with IN, so using JOIN will likely be faster.

Thx, I have edited my solution following your suggestion

Window functions are best for this kind of analysis.
Oracle fortunately allows count(distinct as a window function, otherwise you'd need to hack it with a doubly-nested subquery and dense_rank and min.
select *
from (
    select "primary", groupb, valuec, valued,
      count(distinct groupb) over (partition by valuec) distinct_b,
      count(distinct valued) over (partition by valuec) distinct_d,
      count(*)               over (partition by valuec) c
    from table1 t1
) t1
where c = distinct_b
  and c = distinct_d
  and c > 1;

db<>fiddle
